# converting complex tr command to sed statement

Tags: awk, sed, grep, tr

What is the "best" way to clean up this unix command? (e.g. one clean sed command)

```
cat file.txt | tr '\t' '|' | tr '|\n' '|' | tr -s '|' | tr '"' '\n' | sed "/^|/d"
```

My workflow was something like the following:

1. replace tabs with pipes
2. replace pipe + new line with just a pipe
3. squeeze out duplicate pipes
4. replace " marks with new line
5. remove extra | on each line

(I was having problems using sed to replace tabs, new lines, etc., so that's why I used tr)

Comment: an example would be better.

Comment: It would be much more helpful to show your input and desired output. There are ways to tidy up what you've done but given the knowledge of exactly what you're trying to do, there may be a completely different way of going about it. Please update your question.

Comment: What are the specs of that filter, i.e. what needs to be converted or deleted? Without this, we'd need to reverse-engineer that from your (inelegant) implementation!

Comment: For anything involving multiple input lines simultaneously (e.g. joining lines) you should be using awk. Post some sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n 'H;${s/\t/|/g;s/\|\n/|/g;s/\|{2,\}/|/;s/"/\
/g;s/\(\n\)\|\{1,\}/\1/g;s/.//p;}' file.txt
```

Your order and sequence could hardly be changed due to possibilities to create new elligible pattern after each modification.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\t/|/g;:a;$!N;s/|\n/|/;ta;s/|\+/|/g;s/"/\n/g;s/^|//Mg;P;D' file
```

The last operation is a bit ambiguous - remove the `|` or remove the line?

I chose to remove the `|`.

To remove the line use `s/^|.*$//Mg`.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample input and expected output it's just guesswork but this might do what you want:

```
awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{ gsub(/\t/,"|"); gsub(/\|\n/,"|"); gsub(/\|+/,"|"); gsub(/"/,"\n"); gsub(/(^|\n)\|/,""); print }' file
```

The above uses GNU awk for multi-char RS.

There's probably a simpler awk solution once you show us the expected input/output, the above is just translating your tr and sed commands to awk syntax which may not be idiomatically the best approach.